# What is/was auto_oldpath?

Tags: tcl

According to [tcl.tk](http://www2.tcl.tk/1792):

> auto_oldpath is a global Tcl variable which is set during the
>   auto_load_index proc.

[and](http://www2.tcl.tk/1628)

> auto_path is one of the magic names that Tcl knows. It is described in
>   the Tcl man page, "library". It is a global variable containing a list
>   of directories that Tcl uses when attempting either to resolve
>   packages with the package command, or to resolve commands using
>   auto_load. The package and auto_load commands use auto_path in
>   different ways. auto_load searches the auto_path directories looking
>   for files named tclIndex. These are "Tcl autoload index files", and
>   are formatted in two versions; version 2.0 contains commands set
>   auto_index(::namespace::function_name) $cmd where $cmd typically
>   sources a file that defines the command ::namespace::function_name

which is for me:

```
% puts $auto_path
/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.5 /usr/lib /usr/local/lib/tcltk /usr/local/share/tcltk /usr/lib/tcltk /usr/share/tcltk /usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/ttk
```

but:

```
% puts $auto_oldpath
can't read "auto_oldpath": no such variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable was moved to the `::tcl` namespace.
This variable is set to the value of the `::auto_path` variable when the auto_index is build.
It won't try to load the auto_index again if the contents of `::tcl::auto_oldpath` is equal to the contents of the `::auto_path` variable.

To quote the relevant part of the [`init.tcl`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/57ac4b5aaf3136c4376bf3cfd73c0f6b49909854)

```
proc auto_load_index {} {
    variable ::tcl::auto_oldpath
    global auto_index auto_path

    if {[info exists auto_oldpath] && ($auto_oldpath eq $auto_path)} {
        return 0
    }
    set auto_oldpath $auto_path
    # ....
}
```

Comment: To be clear, that variable is considered to be wholly part of Tcl's implementation and it should not be accessed by any user or extension package code. It's also not guaranteed to exist at any particular time.